# Invalid column name grouping by calculated column label

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run this query to get the sales by month and by account:

```
select 
    left(cast(datekey as varchar(8)), 6) as themonth, 
    account, sum(sales) 
from 
    Sales
where 
    datekey > 20150101
group by 
    themonth, account
order by 
    themonth asc
```

`datekey` is an `int` following the YYYYMMDD format for dates.

I'm getting this message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Invalid column name 'themonth'

Why would that column name be invalid?

I'm assuming the error message is meaningless so what else is wrong with this query?

Comment: You must write `left(cast(datekey as varchar(8)), 6)` in `Group by` not `themonth`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow the alias to be reused in the `GROUP BY` clause (other databases, such as MySQL, do allow for this).  So, one option here would be to just repeat the quantity in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(CAST(datekey AS varchar(8)), 6) AS themonth,
    account,
    SUM(sales)
FROM Sales
WHERE datekey > 20150101
GROUP BY
    LEFT(CAST(datekey AS varchar(8)), 6),
    account
ORDER BY
    themonth;
```

Note that it *is* possible to `ORDER BY` the alias, so you may leave this part of your query as-is.

Comment: @Chapo SQL Server and Oracle tend to be the most inflexible major databases syntax-wise.  If you want an RDBMS with a bit more flexibility, consider something like Postgres or maybe MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Tim Biegeleisen, one more of way is using subquery and achieve the result

```sql
Select     themonth, account, sum(sales) 
from
(select 
    left(cast(datekey as varchar(8)), 6) as themonth, 
    account, sales 
from 
    Sales
where 
    datekey > 20150101) as t
group by 
    themonth, account
order by 
    themonth asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse an alias in the `SELECT` in most of the query.  However, you can define the alias in the `FROM` clause using `APPLY`.  So:

```
select v.themonth, s.account, sum(s.sales) 
from Sales s cross apply
     (values (left(cast(s.datekey as varchar(8)), 6))) v(themonth)
where s.datekey > 20150101
group by v.themonth, s.account
order by v.themonth asc;
```

I don't know exactly what your datekey looks like.  However, if it is an integer, you can simply do:

```
select v.themonth, s.account, sum(s.sales) 
from Sales s cross apply
     (values (floor(s.datekey / 100)) v(themonth)
where s.datekey > 20150101
group by v.themonth, s.account
order by v.themonth asc;
```

Strictly speaking, the `floor()` is not necessary but it makes it clear that you want an integer.